# ColorPicker not displaying dialog

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on making a colorpicker app. I have the layout worked out, but once I press the Change Background button it doesn't load the dialog (Color picker). I'm just wondering how I would go about displaying it and making my app work correctly, thanks. Here is my code for the main activity. I don't think you really need to see the other classes because they are all copy and pasted code but I would be willing to provide them if need be.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.miller.colorpicker;

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.content.SharedPreferences; 
import android.graphics.Color; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            int colour = sharedPref.getInt("colour", Color.WHITE);
            RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
            parent.setBackgroundColor(colour);

            final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_text);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Perform action on click

                }
            });
        } }

04-08 22:16:59.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1144): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 22:16:59.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1144): Process: com.miller.colorpicker, PID: 1144
04-08 22:16:59.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1144): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 22:16:59.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1144):     at com.miller.colorpicker.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:53)
04-08 22:16:59.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1144):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
04-08 22:16:59.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1144):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
04-08 22:16:59.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1144):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-08 22:16:59.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1144):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-08 22:16:59.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1144):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-08 22:16:59.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1144):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-08 22:16:59.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1144):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 22:16:59.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1144):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-08 22:16:59.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1144):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-08 22:16:59.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1144):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-08 22:16:59.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1144):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this sample before:
https://github.com/lomza/android-color-picker

```
// create OnAmbilWarnaListener instance
// new color can be retrieved in onOk() event
OnAmbilWarnaListener onAmbilWarnaListener = new OnAmbilWarnaListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialogFragment dialogFragment) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onCancel()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialogFragment dialogFragment, int color) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onOk(). Color: " + color);

        MainActivity.this.mColor = color;
    }
};

// create new instance of AmbilWarnaDialogFragment and set OnAmbilWarnaListener listener to it
// show dialog fragment with some tag value
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
AmbilWarnaDialogFragment fragment = AmbilWarnaDialogFragment.newInstance(mColor);
fragment.setOnAmbilWarnaListener(onAmbilWarnaListener);

fragment.show(ft, "color_picker_dialog");
```

Comment: I'm using the same sample. Not exactly sure what you're doing in the above code. What is AmbilWarnaDialogFragment?

Comment: AmbilWarnaDialogFragment is the actual ColorPicker dialog that will be displayed. You can add that code inside your button's onClick listener function.

Comment: So I added that code but when I click the button it just crashes.

Comment: Please try using getFragmentManager instead of getSupportFragmentManager.

Comment: That's what I'm using cause it gave me an error originally.

Comment: I used the following code:

FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
AmbilWarnaDialogFragment fragment = AmbilWarnaDialogFragment.newInstance(mColor);
fragment.setOnAmbilWarnaListener(onAmbilWarnaListener);

fragment.show(fm, "color_picker_dialog");

Comment: When I changed the code it gave me the following error...The method show(FragmentTransaction, String) in the type AmbilWarnaDialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentManager, String) but I generated the FragmentManager method and now it's gone.

Comment: Still crashing though.

Comment: Did you just  add the java files and XML from that github project?
If you did , you need to change the ambilwarna_dialog.xml.
Particularly the <yuku.ambilwarna.AmbilWarnaKotak line.
You need to use your own package name there.
In your case, it maybe com.miller.colorpicker.AmbilWarnaKotak